# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, ResultSet found

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I wanted to get the info on a Wikipedia table to a csv file. While searching, I found the code in [this page](https://adesquared.wordpress.com/2013/06/16/using-python-beautifulsoup-to-scrape-a-wikipedia-table/) which was using BeautifulSoup to get the table items to a file.

Little differently, I only wanted to get the info to a file on my computer. I wanted to get the table from this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_planets:_1001%E2%80%932000). I ended up with this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_planets:_1001%E2%80%932000"
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} #Needed to prevent 403 error on Wikipedia
req = urllib2.Request(wiki,headers=header)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

Name = ""
designation = ""
date = ""
site = ""
discoverer = ""
table = soup.find("table")

f = open('output.csv', 'w')

for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll("td")
    #For each "tr", assign each "td" to a variable.
    if len(cells) == 5:
        Name = cells[0].find(text=True)
        designation = cells[1].findAll(text=True)
        date = cells[2].find(text=True)
        site = cells[3].find(text=True)
        discoverer = cells[4].find(text=True)

        for x in range(len(site)):
            write_to_file = (site + ";" + Name + ";" + designation + ";" + 
                             date + ";" + discoverer + "\n")
            print write_to_file
            f.write(write_to_file)

f.close()
```

The only differences are, that I don't have a "sortable table" so I removed that part from the code and I have 5 columns.

However the code returns the following error:

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, ResultSet found

I believe it is related to "\n" in the code, that's where I get the error.

What do you think this problem is and how can I get over it?

Comment: Well, out of curiosity, I removed the "\n" part (not that it will suit my needs, however it still gave the same error. So it is not that, I changed the commas and still got the same error. And, in addition, the code that the guy wrote on the given page above, works OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not related to the '\n', the culprit is this line:

```
designation = cells[1].findAll(text=True)
```

Notice how this line uses `findAll` while the others use `find`.

`findAll` returns a list (actually a `ResultSet`), even if it finds only a single occurrence. Later, when you're building the `write_to_file` string, it raises an error when you try to concatenate the partial string and `designation` (which is a `ResultSet`).

Replace `findAll` with `find` and it works (except for eventual encoding errors)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Converting "findAll"s to find resulted in being cells list having 1 element instead I changed all to findAll which seems to work fine right now.

Answer (score -2):

By converting `write_to_file` with `str(write_to_file)` helped in `print` and `f.write`.